# Drawing a dot on a bar scale based on a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to html/css/js. I wanted to create a color gradient bar and then draw a dot on it based on a variable. I have looked around and from different sources I came up with this, but it's not fully working and I would like to know why.

```js
var A = 38,
  B = 100,
  C = 0,
  D = 300,
  score = 67; // {{crFlag['value']}} will be variable

function init() {
  $('.circle').attr('style', 'left: ' + ((score - A) / (B - A) * (D - C)) + 'px');
};
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #7c7676;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4cd964, #d0ff00, #e0740f, #ff2d55);
}

.circle {
  background: rgba(88, 83, 83);
  width: 10px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Why is the dot not changing position when I give a different score?

Comment: Your `init()` function isn't called from anywhere.

Comment: How do I make it so that the function is called when I load/open the page?

Comment: Using the `onload()` property.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) f you were calling your `init` function at all, you may have been calling it too early (before the DOM had loaded, so before the div with class circle exists).  I added a new script block at the end to call it.

2) You didn't say if you were actually using jQuery or not, but you're using jQuery syntax.  The example below will work without jQuery, but you can uncomment the line I commented out if and only iff you've loaded jQuery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            width: 300px;
            height: 16px;
            border: 1px solid #7c7676;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4cd964, #d0ff00, #e0740f, #ff2d55);
            }

            .circle {
            background: rgba(88, 83, 83);
            width: 10px;
            height: 16px;
            border-radius: 30%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 40px;
            }

        </style>

        <script>
            var A = 38,
            B = 100,
            C = 0, 
            D = 300,
            score = 67; // {{crFlag['value']}} will be variable

            function init(){
                    document.querySelector(".circle").setAttribute("style", 'left: ' + ((score-A)/(B-A)*(D-C)) + 'px' )
                // $('.circle').attr('style', 'left: ' + ((score-A)/(B-A)*(D-C)) + 'px' );
            };
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    init();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `window.onload` to call `init` is probably better form than using a second `script` block, but it should give you the idea.